# Getting data to a JSP without scriptles

Tags: jsp, model-view-controller

I am unable to use JSTL, and I want to eliminate all scriptlets and logic form my JSPs.
I have to use a custom MVC framework, it's similar to Struts 1.

I was thinking of having the controller handle/delegating the making of any beans that are required, and sticking them in the request.
Once in the request, and a JSP gets called, what is the best way to use the bean?

For instance, I will want to populate a dropdown with values that were set in the bean, is my only option here to do a scriptlet, other than roll my yown taglib?

Also, I will need to set write out some values as strings on the page. When there is a bean in the request object, is it possible to make use of jsp:useBean, is that the best thing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain vanilla JSP there are three basic ways to get data onto the page.

1. Scriptlets, which you say you don't want to use.
2. EL, which lets you access variables you've stored in one of the contexts using a convenient syntax. E.g. if you have a Person bean stored in the request under the attribute name "person" you can do `${person.firstName}` which would be the equivalent of `<%=person.getFirstName()%>`
3. Tag libraries. These are not hard to write. But I have to wonder about why you can't use a pre-existing tag library such as JSTL, which would simplify a lot of your work.

Comment: Note that for option 2, you can pass the parameters to the JSP using `request.setAttribute()`.

Comment: do i need to do anything to setup EL? I did a test where I set a Foo object in request in the controller, then in the jsp i did ${foo.age}, and it only printed "${foo.age}"?